# Sequences and indexed families.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

A sequence is a *function* from the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ to (let's say) $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
a:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}.
$$
I have a few remarks/questions:

1. People call  sequence the entire function, so that you don't confuse the sequence with the image of the function, $\text{Im }a=\{a_n \ | \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$?
2. Instead of viewing the sequence as $a:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$, can I consider the image of the *section* defined by $a$ as being my sequence? Namely 
   $$
   \sigma_a:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{R}
   $$
   with $\sigma_a(n):=(n,a_n)$, and hence $\text{Im }\sigma_a=\{(n,a_n) \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, being my sequence?
3. Is the point I made in *2.* what is used when one is constructing a family of objects? For example, when one wants to ``pick'', say, $n$ vectors from a vector space $V$, one uses a function from an index set $I$ (of cardinality $n$)
   $$
   f:I \to V
   $$
   and one writes for this family $f_i(i\in I)$. This last notation confuses me, it cannot mean the image of $f$, as that would be
   $$
   \text{Im }f=\{ f_i \ | \ i\in I \}
   $$
   and if $f$ wasn't injective (for $i\neq j$, $f_i=f_j$) $\text{Im }f$ wouldn't be able to distinguish between $f_i$ and $f_j$.

   Can in be that $f_i(i\in I)$ means precisely
   $$
   \text{Im }\sigma_f =\{(i,f_i) \ | \ i\in I\}
   $$
   so that now even if $f$ picked the same vector for two *different* indices, we could still distinguish the two by the first coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer: keep in mind that the sentence

> let $\{a_n\}_n$ be a sequence

is as correct as saying

> let $f(x)$, $x \in X$, be a function.

A sequence is a function, no matter how you define functions. Any function can be thought of as its graph, and this is exactly what you are doing with your *sections*.

Notation is often lazy, and it is meaningful as long as we understand its meaning. So a sequence is definitely *not* the same as the set of its values, although we tend to use a misleading notation.

Comment: I take by your answer that an indexed family of say vectors, $f_i(i \in I)$ is again a different way of saying let $f:I\to V$.